# Changing a Specific Icon Image

Tags: firefox, icons, themes

How can I change a specific icon's image? Changing the theme would solve the problem, but change the rest of the icons, but I just want to change the firefox icon specifically.

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit the `firefox.desktop` file, that you can find in `/usr/share/applications/`. Run this command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

and edit the entry `Icon` like this:

```
Icon=/path/to/your/icon/your-icon.png
```

To search in nano use this shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and type the string "Icon".